# Object of class (variable) could not be converted to string during assignment

Tags: php, mysqli

I am integrating MySQL into my PHP project an am running into an error. In my constructor of one of my classes I pass the parameters and set them as variables. However, it seems that my $dbc variable is considered a String and therefore giving me the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\Users\Exporting\PhpstormProjects\GameDB\games\price.php on line 21
```

I have done extensive googling revolving this subject, and anything with the same issue I have is from developers making silly mistakes such as calling the method in an echo or something along those lines. I have also tried the **settype()** method. My code as follows:

```
class price_check {

    private $dbc;
    private $name;

    function __construct($dbc, $name) {
        settype($dbc, "object"); // Just for testing to see if it'd work
        $this->$dbc = $dbc; // Line 21
        $this->$name = $name;
    }
}
```

**How I create a new instance of the class:**

```
<head>
    <?php
    require_once("db/mysql_connect.php");
    require_once("content/price_check.php");
    echo "<script> alert('" . gettype($dbc) . "')</script>"; // Returns object, for testing purposes
    $price_check = new crash_session($dbc, "TODO");
    ?>
</head>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Show us how you are calling new price_check

Comment: @RyanTuosto I have updated the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->$dbc` should be `$this->dbc` (no `$` after `->`).

Similarly `$this->$name` should be `$this->name`.